# executing lb help on SQLCl

Tags: liquibase

Please see the below pictures:

Installation
[image: Installation]

Getting help on SQLCl
[image: Getting help on SQLCl]

This command works

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=changelog.sql update
```

Liquibase was successfully installed, but do you known why I can't even execute a simple `lb help` command?

Thank you

Comment: I found the problem, if you want to use liquibase on SQLcl, just install the new version of SQLcl (19.4).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Liquibase into SQLcl, install its last version, you don't need to install the the regular Liquibase client.